# cv::magnitude()の逆の処理を行う関数は？

Tags: opencv

OpenCV2.4.13を使用しています。

`cv::magnitude( vecX, vecY, vec );` でベクトルの大きさを求めることができますが、
逆にベクトルのX成分とY成分を求める関数はOpenCVで用意されていますか？

自前で計算していますが、存在するのならそちらを使ったほうがいいなと思ったので、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ベクトルの大きさが決まっただけではベクトルのX成分とY成分両方を決めることはできません（向きが決まっていないため）。ベクトルの大きさと X, Y どちらか片方の成分が与えられたときに、他方の成分を計算したいということでしょうか？　あるいは、ベクトルの大きさと方向ベクトルが与えられたときに、そのベクトルの X, Y 成分を求めたいということでしょうか。

Comment: すみません。勘違いをしていました。方向ベクトルも与えられたときの関数です。

Answer (score 1):

ベクトルの大きさと、正規化された (つまり、長さが1の) 方向ベクトルが分かるなら、ベクトルのスカラー倍を計算すればそのベクトルの各成分を求めることができます。

たとえばベクトルの大きさが浮動小数点数型の変数 `dist` として与えられ、方向ベクトルのリストが `cv::Mat` 型の変数 `dir` として与えられるのであれば、`dist * dir` で計算ができます。`vecX` や `vecY` の形式にしたいなら、計算結果に対して `cv::Mat::row` や `cv::Mat::col` を使って抽出すると良いです。